# spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create does not create tables in Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I upgrade Sping Boot from 1.5.3 to 2.0.0.M2. Now hibernate does not create tables even with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create. It works under Spring Boot 1.5.3. Part of my related configuration is as the following:

```
#database configuration
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/gzhtestdb
spring.datasource.username=gzhtest
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxxxx
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=generated/sql/create.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create
```

The console log shows:

```
    2017-07-20 16:22:33.285  INFO 82524 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
2017-07-20 16:22:33.285  INFO 82524 --- [  restartedMain] 
    org.hibernate.cfg.Environment : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    2017-07-20 16:22:33.331  INFO 82524 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
    2017-07-20 16:22:33.519  INFO 82524 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    2017-07-20 16:22:33.597  INFO 82524 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    2017-07-20 16:22:33.597  INFO 82524 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@8858d27
    2017-07-20 16:22:34.408  INFO 82524 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@31b797e'
    2017-07-20 16:22:36.546  INFO 82524 --- [  restartedMain] com.cju.BeanProvider : @PostConstruct init() called!
```

Comment: i think it is compatibility issue in spring and hibernate versions

Comment: I am using hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar and hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar. I did not specify version numbers for these two jars. They are managed by Sping Boot 2.0.0.M2.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.*` resolves the problem.